# finding patent ZL 2007 3 0024190.5 portable fan

Tags: patent-search, china

I purchased a rechargeable clip on fan. This model is available from various re sellers but i want to find the manufacturer. I am hoping the patent number will get me to them. The number on the fan is ZL 2007 3 0024190.5.I cannot find any information on online, i have tried google patent search,cnpat plus others and nothing works. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I also failed searching. I tried searching on The Lens specifying China as the jurisdiction and 2007 as the filing date with "fan" as the search word. Nothing at all showed up. It's China so it might be a fake patent number anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The patent you are referring related to Chinese design patents and are not readily searchable through text you can find the details at http://epub.cnipa.gov.cn/gjcx.jsp

Comment: The linked page is entirely in Chinese. Is it possible to provide a link to the actual patent?

Comment: OK - I was looking at inventions and utility models. If it is a design, there is a WIPO database at "https://www.wipo.int/reference/en/designdb/news/2019/news_0001.html that says it leads to a global design database that now includes the entire China design database. Didn't find either number there.

Answer (score -1):

the right patent number is ZL200730024196.9

Comment: How do you know this is the right patent number? Also, if this is the right patent number than providing an explanation on how you figured it out and a link to it would make the answer much more useful.

Comment: The English version of the site is http://114.247.84.106:8080/sipo_EN/search/tabSearch.do?method=init

Comment: And I didn't find either number there

Comment: There are about 700 application in China in 2007 (using link I provided above) with the word "fan" in the English Title. All are in the 2007 2's. None are 2007 3 anything. Trying "fan" in Abstract got 0 hits. I'm done.